# Reads And Updates XML in pycharm but not command line

Tags: python, xml, encoding, pycharm, python-3.6

I am very new to python and SO. The script opens xml files inside of a folder. Using os.walk I iterate over the collection and open the file and then calls the function to iterate over the xml file and update the xml file rewriting the updated file over the original using .writexml. the problem is when i run this program from the command line the it says there is an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./XMLParser.py", line 67, in <module>
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 928, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 5614: ordinal not in range(128)
```

CODE:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

import os

import codecs

'''
Function to iterate over the directory that contains the work items
params:
    CoreID of new author,
    x is the path to the workItem.xml file,
    p is the path to the workItem.xml that will be overwritten with new data
'''
def changeauthor(coreid, x, p):
# Gets the content of the xml based within the work item tag.
testcase = x.getElementsByTagName("work-item")[0]

# All fields are stored as a <field> tag with the id attribute being the
# differentiators between them. Fields is a list of all the field tags in the
# document.
fields = testcase.getElementsByTagName("field")

# Loop iterates over the field tags and looks for the one tag where the id
# attribute has a value of author. when this tag is found the tags value is
# updated to the core id passed to the function.
for field in fields:
    attribute = field.attributes['id'].value
    if attribute == "author":
        # print the current author.
        print("Previous Author: ", field.firstChild.data)
        # Set the author to the core id entered into the script
        field.firstChild.data = coreid
        # Print the updated author field
        print("New Author: ", field.firstChild.data)
        # Create a temp file with the same path as the source
        tmp_config = p
        # Open the new temp file with the write mode set.
        with codecs.open(tmp_config, 'w', "utf-8") as f:
        # f = open(tmp_config, 'w')
        # Write the xml into the file at the same location as the orginal
            x.writexml(f)
        # Close the file
        # f.close()

return


while True:
    core = str(input("Enter Core ID of the new author: "))
    core = core.upper()
    spath = str(input("Please enter the full path to the directory of test cases: "))
    count = 0
    confirm = str(input("Confirm path and core id (Y/N or Exit to leave script): "))
    confirm = confirm.upper()
    if confirm == "Y":
        '''Hard code path here and comment out line above asking for input either will work.'''
        # spath = "/Users/Evan/Desktop/workitems-r583233"

        # Loop iterates over the directory. Whenever a workitem.xml file is found the path is stored and the file is
        # parsed. the core ID entered and the path as well as the parsed xml doc are passed to the change author
        # function.
        for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(spath):
            for file in files:
                title = file.title()
                if title == "Workitem.Xml":
                    path = os.path.join(roots, file)
                    with codecs.open(path, 'r+', "utf-8") as xml:
                        xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml)
                    lst = path.split('/')
                    wi = lst[5]
                    print("Updating: ", wi)
                    changeauthor(core, xmldoc, path)
                    count += 1
                    print(wi, "updated succesfully.")
                    print("-------------------------------")
        if count > 0:
            # Print how many test cases were updated.
            print("All Done", count, "workItems updated!")
        else:
            print("Please double check path and try again no workItems found to update!")
   elif confirm == "N":
       continue
   elif confirm == "EXIT":
       break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse unicode strings with minidom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329668/how-to-parse-unicode-strings-with-minidom)

Comment: should i be opening the file as a normal file and then parsing each line using the mini dom parse string method?

Comment: Yes, just send `path` directly to `minidom.parse()` without opening file. If it will give character error again, then open file, as a string object, encode and decode it, then pass it to `minidom.parseString()` as a string.

Comment: will I still be able to use the method writexml to write the file over the original?